# Thanx for all the flags

Tags: discussion, flagging

Ok, this is not actually a question. It's a way to say thank you to all of you who constantly provide your fellow moderators with flags of content that needs our help. We have no other possibility to review all content provided here, if you weren't here to help us.

Over the last 14 months (I've been moderating SP.SE) we have received more than 2000 flags which are very accurate. Seldom do we see flags that are inappropriate (less than 1%). If you weren't there to help us, a lot of our valuable content would be less valuable. You help us making this site a resource on questions and answers that we do not know the answer of.

SharePoint is so complex that it actually need a site like this to enable the great work it can do. And you help us to make that happen. We've all seen our questions and answers in our sometimes frustrating searches for explaination of how this actually works. And our answers get higher and higher in ranking, all thanks to you who bring us flags making the site better and more accurate.

So keep those flags coming, they make all the difference!

Comment: *almost flags this post out of sheer patriotism*

Comment: @user Do it! :-)